# Default type of id function

Tags: haskell

What type will have id function if I apply this function to an empty list? Is there some default type for id function or it depends on default type of list?

```
id []
```

Comment: It will just have type `id [] :: [a]`, so you can use this for whatever `a` you want.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But it should return some concrete type, am I right?

Comment: @EricGrey: why should this be a concrete type?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't know, it's a new language for me, I just thought about printing empty list, which is impossible if we haven't defined type of list

Comment: @EricGrey: there are some default rules at the end, but the concrete type of `id []` is derived from the context. For example if one uses `map (:"") (id [])`, it is clear that the list is a list of `String`s.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem okey, so, if I apply filter function to it, e.g. `filter id []`, then return type will be bool?

Comment: @EricGrey: in that case the `[]` will be a list of `Bool`s, since you use `id` as *filter function*, and since `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` requires the filter function to be `a -> Bool`, and `id` has type `b -> b`, it reasons that `a ~ b ~ Bool`, and thus that `a` and `b` are `Bool`s, and thus `filter id []` "collapses" to `[Bool]`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you! I think I understood this logic

Answer (score 1):

**In short**: `id []` has type `[a]`, the exact type will depend on the context of the caller.

We can perform the reasoning of the types ourselves. We basically have two items here: `id` and `[]`, `id` has as type [**`id :: a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:id), and `[]` is just a constructor, so it has type **`[] :: [b]`**.

So we can derive the type with:

```
  id :: a   -> a
  [] :: [b]
----------------
  a ~ [b]
```

we thus conclude that the `a` in `id :: a -> a` is the same type as `[b]`, and hence it means that the type of the result of `id []`, is `a` which is equal to `[b]`, so that means that:

```
id [] :: [b]
```

We get the same result when we let `ghci` derive the type of `id []`:

```
Prelude> :t id []
id [] :: [t]
```

Of course in a real program if you use `id []`, it will "collapse" to a certain type. That type depends on the use of `id []`, so of the "caller". For example if we call this with:

```
putStrLn (id [])
```

Since [**`putStrLn`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn) expects a `String` as parameter, this means that `id []` in *this* context should be a `String`. A `String` is just an *alias* for `[Char]`. So the type system reasons that in that case `b ~ Char`, so the list `[]` is in this context an empty list of `Char`s.

But if we would use it in the context of `sum (id [])`, then the type would be totally different, since we can not `sum`up `Char`s, since we can only sum up types that are members of the `Num` type class.

In case the ambiguity of the type ramains, Haskell has some [defaulting rules [Kwang's Haskell blog]](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-04-type-defaulting-in-haskell.html). The [Haskell '10 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4) for example also has a section on defining defaults for type classes.